# Link C Flex lexer to C++ parser

Tags: c++, c

I am using Flex to develop a lexer for a language of mine.
I want to create the parser in C++ and I am using my own approach for it. Since the lexer is in C (Flex), I want to compile the lexer (`gcc -c lex.yy.c -lfl`) and my program (`g++ -c file1.cc file2.cc ...`) separately and then link them together to create the final executable.

In particular, after creating the lexer, I write the following code for my C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>

extern int yylex();
int main(int argc, char** argv);

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  yylex();
  return 0;
}
```

But I get link error when I link stuff together like:

```
g++ main.cc lex.yy.o -lfl
```

But I always get:

```
/tmp/ccBrHObp.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `yylex()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where is the problem? Thankyou

Comment: This has nothing to do with lexers, parsers, gcc, or g++. The problem is that you need to say `extern "C"` when referring to a C function from C++.

Comment: http://boost-spirit.com/home/ is likely to be a better choice in your case ...

Comment: Even though I think that n.m. is right, please post your exact error, so we can see what it doesn't like.

Comment: I am not compiling all these things together, I compile them separately and then link them together... I think extern only is enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that you compile the C code, which is something like this:

```
int yylex() {
  // ...
}
```

It generates a `yylex` symbol. Then you compile the C++ code. As C++ allows two different functions with the same name to exist, it can't just use the name of the function as the symbol name. When you write `int yylex();` on C++ code, GCC looks for this symbol: `_Z5yylexv`. It doesn't find, link error. The solution is to say that this is a C function and we should use its name as symbol name:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
int yylex();

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  std::cout << yylex() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```